# remote wevtutil "The account is not authorized to log in from this station."

Tags: windows, powershell, remote-access, system-administration, wevtutil

I am responsible for running centralized backups of Windows Security logs on a network of ~15 Windows boxes. To automate this task, I have been writing a Powershell script that utilizes wevtutil's /r parameter to do it all remotely. All of the boxes are connected to a Sharepoint network drive that I was hoping to copy the logs to so that I could centralize all of the logs, but I've run into some trouble.

The script runs fine when I pass it the ip of the Windows box that it's running on. The logs are copied to the Sharepoint without a hitch. The script also runs fine when I just tell it to copy the logs locally. However, when the script trys to remotely copy the computer's log to the sharepoint, I get a `Failed to Archive Security log. The account is not authorized to log in from this station.` error.

The format of the command is

`wevtutil epl Security \\path\to\sharepoint\[hostname]-[datetime]Security.evtx /r:[hostname]`

I am running the script as a domain admin. I have also ran  the script with the credentials of a local admin and I got a generic access denied error.

A google search for the error message mostly includes computers not being able to access network drives (not remote wevtutil specifically) and include a lot of messing around in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters
```

or

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
```

which have not yielded any results. I am also restricted to Powershell 1, so I cannot use Powershell itself remotely AFAIK.

I could just put the script on each machine and run it locally with task scheduler, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution. Does anyone have experience with using wevtutil in this way and can point me in the right direction, or perhaps even suggest a better technique/tool?

Answer (score 0):

How much latitude do you have to implement another solution?

If you wanted to do something with the logs, or make them easily searchable, you could set up a free Splunk server and either use a Splunk forwarder to ship the logs off box, or you could also use Powershell to send the logs to Splunk's HTTP event collector.